# Isolate a specific author from a bibliography entry with multiple authors

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, cross-referencing, natbib

Suppose I have the following entry in my `references.bib` file

```
@incollection{sampleref,
  author      = "Author 1 and Author 2",
  title       = "Sample Title",
  booktitle   = "A sample book title",
  publisher   = "Custom Monographs",
  year        = 2020,
  pages       = "1-10",
  chapter     = 1,
}
```

In addition, I have the following minimal code.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,openany,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}

It was \citeauthor{sampleref} % would like to isolate author 2
in \cite{sampleref} who came up with Theorem X.

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % to use natbib
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

I'm using `natbib` and I would like to specifically refer to Author 2.
If I use `\citeauthor{sampleref}`, I get `Author 1 and Author 2` appear in the body.

Is it possible to use `\citeauthor` or some other technique to isolate for one specific author in a `.bib` entry that has multiple authors?

Comment: It is not really supported to pick out a particular author in BibTeX/`natbib` and since you would have to know their position in the author list beforehand anyway, it is probably not much extra work to type the name directly. That's what I would do if I were to refer to a particular author directly.

Comment: Completely unrelated to the actual question, but strictly speaking `\bibliography{references.bib}` is wrong input. `\bibliography` takes the file name of your bibliography database without the `.bib` extension. So `\bibliography{references}` would be correct. Some older systems would not find the file correctly if you erroneously included the `.bib` extension.

Comment: @moewe it you type the author's name you just get plain text, but with `\citeauthor` you get hyperlinked text to the entry in the bibliography. That's the reason I would like to use `\citeauthor` (in order to get that hyperlink to the reference). Thanks for the info about the `.bib` extension. I removed it.

Comment: It is possible to create a command that lets you link to the bibliography entry (or at least it should be possible, I'm sure I have seen something like that before and I have a rough idea of how one would go about creating one), so if you insist on a link that could be a workaround. Unfortunately, `natbib` really doesn't have the full list of authors available in machine-usable form in the citations. It is not impossible to build a `\citeauthor` that lets you retrieve an arbitrary name, but it would need quite some work.

Comment: @moewe that solution would work for me since I only require it in about two places. Do you have a link to posting with that question please?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the link at hand. I will try to find it (or find the implementation of that command, whichever is quicker).

Comment: @moewe thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`natbib` does not really have the list of authors of your citation available in machine-readable form in citations. So a command that lets you typeset a *particular* author of your citation is a bit tricky to implement.

So I suggest you just type the name manually. If you want to be able to link it, the following should help you

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\linktocite}[2]{%
  \hyper@natlinkstart{#1}#2\hyper@natlinkend}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author    = {Humphrey Appleby and James Hacker and Annie Hacker and Bernard Wolley},
  title     = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  year      = {1980},
  publisher = {Pub \& Co.},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{appleby}

\linktocite{appleby}{Annie Hacker}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Annie Hacker. linked]

---

Just for fun here is a `biblatex` implementation of a `\citespecificauthor` command that lets you pick the specific author you want to cite. The implementation is a bit longer than I initially thought, but that is mainly to make the input a little more intuitive. We are abusing the postnote argument to pass the author number and so we need a few tricks to get things right.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, maxbibnames=999, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname:noetal}{%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefixi}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:given-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi}

\makeatletter
\protected\def\nmu@ifinstr#1#2{%
  \def\nmu@ifinstr@i##1#2##2\nmu@end{%
    \notblank{##2}}%
  \nmu@ifinstr@i#1#2\nmu@end}

\newcommand*{\printspecificlabelname@n}[1]{%
  \nmu@ifinstr{#1}{-}
    {\printnames[labelname:noetal][#1]{labelname}}
    {\printnames[labelname:noetal][#1-#1]{labelname}}}

\newcommand*{\printspecificlabelname@x}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\x{\endgroup\printspecificlabelname@n{#1}}%
  \x}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citespecificauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}}
  {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
     \iffieldundef{postnote}
       {\printnames{labelname}}
       {\printspecificlabelname@x{\thefield{postnote}}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author    = {Humphrey Appleby and James Hacker and Annie Hacker and Bernard Wolley},
  title     = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  year      = {1980},
  publisher = {Pub \& Co.},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,appleby}

\citespecificauthor[3]{appleby}

\citespecificauthor[1-2]{appleby}

\citespecificauthor{appleby}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

If you tweak your `.bst` style to produce a machine-readable list of names for each entry, you can implement something similar with `natbib`.

The key is to use `plainnat-namelist.bst` from https://gist.github.com/moewew/80f83c4c93a9f0cdf4fada246b454fe2 instead of `plainnat.bst`. The diff to `plainnat.bst` is

```
--- plainnat.bst    2010-09-14 11:10:56.000000000 +0200
+++ plainnat-namelist.bst   2020-08-01 14:26:49.739944200 +0200
@@ -1,3 +1,11 @@
+%%%% plainnat-namelist.bst
+%%%% A version of plainnat that extracts the author names in
+%%%% machine-readable format for further use on the LaTeX side.
+%%%% The new macro is make.list.names and friends.
+%%%% 2020-08-01 MW
+%%%% for https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/556932/35864
+%%%%
+%%%% original copyrght header follows
 %% File: `plainnat.bst'
 %% A modification of `plain.bst' for use with natbib package 
 %%
@@ -373,6 +381,65 @@
   if$
 }
 
+FUNCTION {format.list.names}
+{'s :=
+  #1 'nameptr :=
+  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
+  numnames 'namesleft :=
+    { namesleft #0 > }
+    { "\namelistitem{"
+      cite$ *
+      "}{" *
+      nameptr int.to.str$ *
+      "}{" *
+      s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ *
+      "}" *
+      write$
+      newline$
+      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
+      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
+    }
+  while$
+}
+
+FUNCTION {author.editor.list}
+{ author empty$
+    { editor empty$
+        { "" }
+        { editor format.list.names }
+      if$
+    }
+    { author format.list.names }
+  if$
+}
+
+FUNCTION {author.list}
+{ author empty$
+    { "" }
+    { author format.list.names }
+  if$
+}
+
+FUNCTION {editor.list}
+{ editor empty$
+    { "" }
+    { editor format.list.names }
+  if$
+}
+
+FUNCTION {make.list.names}
+{ type$ "book" =
+  type$ "inbook" =
+  or
+    'author.editor.list
+    { type$ "proceedings" =
+        'editor.list
+        'author.list
+      if$
+    }
+  if$
+}
+
 FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
 { newline$
   "\bibitem[" write$
@@ -385,6 +452,8 @@
   cite$ write$
   "}" write$
   newline$
+  make.list.names
+  newline$
   ""
   before.all 'output.state :=
 }
@@ -1420,6 +1489,8 @@
   write$ newline$
   "  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi"
   write$ newline$
+  "  \providecommand{\namelistitem}[3]{}"
+  write$ newline$
 }
 
 EXECUTE {begin.bib}
```

Then it is just a matter of using that data.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\namelistitem}[3]{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\namelistitemaux{#1}{#2}{#3}}}

\newcommand*{\namelistitemaux}[3]{%
  \csgdef{nmu@namelist@#1@#2}{#3}}

\newcommand*{\citespecificauthor}[2]{%
  \hyper@natlinkstart{#1}%
  \ifcsundef{nmu@namelist@#1@#2}
    {\textbf{??}}
    {\csuse{nmu@namelist@#1@#2}}%
  \hyper@natlinkend}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author    = {Humphrey Appleby and James Hacker and Annie Hacker and Bernard Wolley},
  title     = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  year      = {1980},
  publisher = {Pub \& Co.},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{appleby}

\citespecificauthor{appleby}{2}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat-namelist}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```